# The CSV Data file in jmeter is picking values in an alternative way

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using 3 API's and 2 of the 3  API's have should run the same data set. With this Instance, 2 one 3 API's should be run simultaneously with a 5 minutes delay for which I use the startup delay so when I specify the csv data set for a particular API the data is taken in a alternative way.

Thread Group settings: I have to run the test for One hour
users: 25
ramp up: 120
Loop Count: infinite
Specify Thread Life time: 3600
I tried with all the settings in the sharing mode, it does not seem to take in a consecutive way
please help me im in a deadline.

For the data from the CSV data file to be taken in a consecutive way instead its taken in a alternative way

Answer (score 0):

With the default [CSV Data Set Config Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of `All threads` each thread (virtual user) picks next line from the CSV file on each iteration.

So if you have only one [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) there should be no "alternative" ways, all the data from the CSV file will go "consecutively".

For example my CSV file looks like:

```
line1
line2
line3
etc.
```

and as you can see the data flow sequentially:

[image]